# including different webpages with a session variable in php

Tags: php, session, indexing, include

Hello every one I have a doubt in php .IN our project we need to include all the palges into our index.php. Header and footer are same for all the pages.But body should change as per the redirecting of each page.And according to our client that redirection should happen in index page only.
So we should not use in the following manner
header('location:login.php');
we need to use like
header('location:index.php?getpage="register.php"');

and in index page we need to check the condition 
if(getpage contains value)
{
redirect to getpage url
}
else
{
redirect to login page
}

But my problem is how to check the condition in index page if Iam using $session of getpage it is showing error that getpage variable is not declared.Please tell solution for my problem
Answer will be highly appreciated

Comment: Which one is our project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have

session_start();

at the top of your php code before any other php on the page?

Without this you'll lose your session variables from page to page.

What you desire to do is change just the body of the page using a $_GET or $_SESSION variable, so in the  tag you want `<? include ($_GET['getpage] . ".inc.php") ?>`

So if you pass index.php?getpage=register

it will include register.inc.php in your body content.

Please note if you're dealing with anything important you might want to escape out special chars etc, but I'm just answering the question.

If you want to override it with a session variable then I'd do something like this

```
if($_SESSION['getpage']) {$getpage = $_SESSION['getpage'];} else { if($_GET['getpage']) {$getpage = $_GET['getpage'];} else {$getpage ='home';}}
```

then call `<? include($getpage) . ".inc.php") ?>` in your body

Comment: AH its working thanks and one more thing is .In one of my webpages i.e in delete.php I have link like this <a href=index.php?getpage=edit.php?id=$row['id']></a> How can i get that into the same body content because it has two links ?

Comment: If you want to include your 'id' page inside your 'edit' page, then I'd just look for the id variable inside your edit page, `<? if ($_GET[id]) { *do whatever you want to do with your id page * } ?>`